# Unfortunately, Application has stopped

Tags: java, android

i am facing a serious problem. i want to get latitude and longitude but application stopped abnormally. i don't know why. i also took permission in menifest. kindly help me, any kind of help will be highly appreciated. Thanks

```
This is my Fragment

public class FragmentThree extends Fragment {
    FindLocation  Fl;
    GPSTracker  gps;
    public FragmentThree() {
        Fl = new FindLocation();
        gps = new GPSTracker(getActivity());
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.location, container, false);
        Location location = gps.getLocation();
        String latLongString = gps.updateWithNewLocation(location);
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), latLongString, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return view;
   }
}

GpsTracker.java

public class GPSTracker {
    Context mContext;

     public GPSTracker(Context mContext){
           this.mContext = mContext;
     }

    public Location getLocation(){
        LocationManager locationManager;
        String context = Context.LOCATION_SERVICE;
        locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext.getSystemService(context);

        String provider = LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

        return location;
    }

    public String updateWithNewLocation(Location location) {
        String latLongString;

        if (location != null){
            double lat = location.getLatitude();
            double lng = location.getLongitude();
            latLongString = "Lat:" + lat + "\nLong:" + lng;
        }else{
            latLongString = "No Location";
        }

        return latLongString;
    }
}
```

Comment: Here is Logca
app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
03-18 22:01:40.741: E/AndroidRuntime(15169):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-18 22:01:40.741: E/AndroidRuntime(15169):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-18 22:01:40.741: E/AndroidRuntime(15169):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:825)
03-18 22:01:40.741: E/AndroidRuntime(15169):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:641)
03-18 22:01:40.741: E/AndroidRuntime(15169):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Answer (score 3):

```
 gps = new GPSTracker(getActivity());
```

getActivity returns null at instantiation time. You have to wait until the fragment is attached to the `Activity`. You should wait until `onAttach` is called. Also `getLastKnownLocation` returns null if a location has not yet been acquired

Comment: same problem even after onAttach method. Moreover, Activity does not return null.